# background color styling is not working

Tags: css

```
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

The background color of the radio button in not changing when I select it.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qjuo92ex/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogrJrq), in it you will find a demonstration.

```
input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
}

input[type=radio] + label:before{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:16px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before{
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Next time create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) so we can experiment a bit, before giving you an answer.

Comment: codepens and jsfiddle are not necessary since you've got the whole code